# Minecraft Xbox One: Can you trade for ender pearls/eyes of ender?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

In the Xbox One edition, is it possible to trade with the villagers to get Ender Pearls or Eyes of Ender?

I've seen a trading chart for Minecraft, but after trading a lot it doesn't seem to match up with what I am seeing. I'm guessing the Xbox One edition is different.

The chart I've already found:[image]

Comment: My experience on the Xbox 360 version has been that they each villager offers exactly one trade, so if your world doesn't generate with a villager offering the trade you want you might be out of luck. Given the much larger size of worlds on the Xbox One, there are likely to be multiple villages to check out.

Comment: The trading seems to work as it does on pc, i.e. there are multiple levels. Just ive never been offered the eyes of ender, as the chart in my post states.

Comment: This [link](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/survival-mode/294425-villager-trading-mechanics-mega-thread) explains my confusion: You have to actually do the trade on the right hand offer to unlock more offers. Because I never actually traded with them they only ever offered the one thing.

Answer (score 1):

So, I did a bit more researching, and I tried a few more times, turns out there must be some randomness to the higher trade items you get first, after a few more goes and reloading of the save I managed to get the Eye of Ender as a trade.

[image: Eyes of Ender for trade | Xbox One]